# The stack trace from Unwind_Backtrace does not match map file addresses

Tags: android, c, android-ndk, backtrace

Created a function pair to produce stack dumps (backtrace wannabe) using Unwind_Backtrace. However, the resulting dump of addresses have no correlation with addresses I'm seeing in the linker map file.  What am I doing wrong?
It seems all the addresses in the map file are relative versus the stack dump are absolute.  If that is the case, where do I get the base address.
Is there a "Dummies guide to Unwind_Backtrace" someone can point me towards?

```c
    static void dbg_log( DebugTopic_type topic, 
                         tDebugLevel_type lvl, 
                         const char *str )
    {
    // stuff
    // more stuff
    // ...
        if ( lvl >= DEBUG_LEVEL_ERR || lvl == DEBUG_LEVEL_VERBOSE )
        {
          int depth = 0;
          _Unwind_Backtrace(trace_callback, &depth);
        }
    }
```

The following code I found online, with minor mods for this implementation:

```c
static _Unwind_Reason_Code trace_callback(struct _Unwind_Context *ctx, void *d)
{
  _Unwind_Reason_Code reason = _URC_NO_REASON;
  int   *depth = (int*)d;
  char  buf[100];

  snprintf( buf, 100, "\t#%d:\tsf:%p\tip:%p\n", *depth,
            (void*)_Unwind_GetRegionStart(ctx),
            (void*)_Unwind_GetIP(ctx));
  (*depth)++;
  nw_dbgout( DEBUG_LEVEL_VERBOSE, buf, strlen(buf));

  if ( *depth >= 10 )
  {
    reason = _UA_CLEANUP_PHASE;
  }
  return reason;
}
```

Together they produce the following output:

```
    #0: sf:0x51e3e3e8   ip:0x51e3e4c2
    #1: sf:0x51e3e718   ip:0x51e3e764
    #2: sf:0x51e778bc   ip:0x51e7794c
    #3: sf:0x51e7a6b8   ip:0x51e7a728
    #4: sf:0x51e7b640   ip:0x51e7b678
    #5: sf:0x408b2e40   ip:0x408b2eb4
    #6: sf:0x408ed418   ip:0x408ed5be
    #7: sf:0x408b2fc0   ip:0x408c4cd0
    #8: sf:0x408c887c   ip:0x408c8938
    #9: sf:0x40901198   ip:0x40901404
```

Comment: LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D__u_char_defined -DANDK -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fexceptions -O0 -gdwarf-2 -rdynamic

Answer (score 1):

This might help you: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-ndk/F1q_qw5MFfU

The problem is that your ips are offsetted with the address where the library has been loaded. See especially GetLibraryAddress() in the link above.

Comment: ok.. So the delta between those from the dump and the loaded offset should match those from the map file...  thx..